# MVC - Passing ReturnUrl to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

I want to redirect to Login Page on Click and when the login is verified, I would like to get back to the previous location.

```
 <a style="display: none;" class="user-menu-links" href="/Account/Login">Login</a>
```

How can I pass Return Url which is the current location? Is my approach right one or is there any better approach?

Comment: pass current url as querystring to login (`?returnUrl=Request.Url`) and use that to redirect to after successful login.

Comment: Or even `@Request.Url` :)

Comment: @user3757426, This is related to three things, 1. Your Login Get Method, 2. Your Login Form 3. Your Login Post Method. But you din't add any of them. Add these three things please.

Answer (score 0):

For redirecting to another view you can use this:

```
     @Html.ActionLink("DisplayLinkName", "View", "Controller", new { @Parameter= parametervalue }, null)
```

Another Approach is this:

```
    <a href="@Url.Action("View", "Controller", new {Parameter = parameterValue})'></a>
```

These work similar to your approach, but these use html helpers instead of pure html. It usually depends on your own preference. html helpers mostly help developers who are less familiar with html tags, and makes it easier for them.

if you want to pass your current location in your own implementation, you can use this:

```
    <a  class="user-menu-links" href="/Controller/View?Parameter="+Parametervalue>Login</a>
```

There are other ways as well to pass your current View if you have used razor views like using session variables and tempdata variables. However without seeing your controller implementation and login form i cannot tell you how to use them.